# Drupal site keeps on redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal, drupal-7

Base URL is already set to in the settings.php file

```
$base_url = 'https://<site_name>.com.au";
```

But when accesssing it thru `www.<site_name>.com.au` it seems that it will have a redirect loop.

Here's the .htaccess Rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What's happen if you remove custom rewrites into .htaccess (restart apache after it) and add to settings.php  `$conf['HTTPS'] = true;` ?

Answer (score 0):

When enforcing or stripping www, to avoid a bounce between HTTP and HTTPS, you should also uncomment the following in the .htaccess file:

```
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]
```

The comments in the default .htaccess file define the above lines in function as such:

> Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
>     if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
>     you don't bounce between http and https.

If you're adding the lines manually, make sure they precede your re-write, but come after

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on`